# Hibernate Criteria restriction and minimum date

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a question about getting minimum date from criteria. I have to create criteria, set some restrictions, and then choose one record with minimum value of Date field from oracle table:

```
Criteria cr = oracleSessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Statement.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("id", Id)).add(Restrictions.eq("code",Code))
            .add(Restrictions.in("Codes", codes))
            .setMaxResults(Integer.parseInt(noOfRecord))
            .setProjection(Projections.min("businessDate"));
```

The error I am getting after using this is

```
ERROR: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

Comment: You need to check if `businessDate` is a date field rather than a varchar field.